# Outliner (software) with annotations for OS X or browser based (but offline!)

Tags: software, outline

Okay, there are like a billion outliners out there but I'm not sure if there is one that does what I want. Maybe you can help.

- I want to write chunks of text **without headline, numbering, bullets**. Just text like in a text editor, one sentence/paragraph/fragment after another.
- One chunk of text should appear immediately below the other. Also just like text in a text editor window.
- I want to be able to create **columns of annotations** that represent the story throughlines, e.g. one column for the protagonist's outer quest, one column for his inner development, one for the antagonist, one for the romance, and so on.
- I want to be able to drag each row of outline+annoations to anywhere else in the document, or copy/paste it.
- I want to be able to copy **only the outline text** without annotations and paste it into a separate text document so you can read, print or mail it around.
- It would be perfect but I guess no software has this feature if I could draw arrows from any part of the document to any other.

Here is what the working area should look like. Done in Excel, which does what I want, but which I hate because it is so visually unappealing and constantly reminds me that I'm writing text into a software that was made to deal with data.

[image]

Comment: I am a huge fan of Scrivener, but I don't know if that will work for you for this task. Someone else suggested another product by the same company called Scapple. http://literatureandlatte.com/scapple.php I have never used it. Maybe give it a poke and see if it works for you?

Comment: Scrivener can indeed do most of this. The feature is called "custom meta-data." I wrote about it in another answer: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8938/software-for-developing-and-organizing-characters/8943#8943

Answer (score 2):

Apples own Numbers app is what you looking for, it's excel injected with desktop publishing steroids. Else there is omnioutliner one of the best there is for this exact requirement...